# Logging name of the script - futile.logger R

Tags: r, logging

I'm using package `futile.logger` to have log message written in a file `log.txt`.
Since my projects is made up of 6 scripts and 20-22 functions I'd like to have a message logged with name of the scripts and name of the function.
I created a `Logging` function that should be called to log the message:

```
Logging<-function(level,message)
{
  #' Logs event to a Log/log.txt files 
  #' 
  #' @param level: String, Message level: info,error,debug (NO CAPS LOCK)
  #' @param message: String, Message you want to Log
  #'
  #' @return  write the file with the message specified by the user.

  flog.appender(appender.file(file.path(getwd(),'Log/logs.txt')))
  eval(parse(text=sprintf("flog.%s('%s')",level,message)))
}
```

Let's suppose a file named  `foo.R` with a function `fun_1`:

```
    fun_1 <- function(input){
       #doing some stuff
       Logging("info","some log message")
                            }
```

Which logs something like:

```
INFO [date hours] some log message
```

I 'd like to have a message that that contain also name of the scripts from which `Logging` function was called and name of the function where the `Logging` function was called i.e

```
 INFO foo fun_1 [date hours] some log message
```

Thanks

Comment: For future reference and readers, a possible workaround is to call `match.call()[[1]]`inside the body of the function you want to log error or successful execution and paste into the message string you are going to pass to the Logging function.

Comment: Any updates on this? i am facing a similar situation and i would appreciate any solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit late, but now `futile.logger` provides such a functionality.

Namely, you can try

```
fun_1 <- function() {

   # doing some stuff
   flog.info("some log message")}
```

then in your main file

```
require(futile.logger)
# create output layout based on documentation and your needs
layout <- layout.format('[~l] [~f] [~t] ~m')
# set the created output
flog.layout(layout)

flog.threshold(DEBUG)
fun_1()
flog.appender(appender.file("log_example.log")))
```

in `log_example.log` which is stored in the project's wd you can check your output